# How to adjust bar absolute width in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, matlab-figure

I'm confused with the bar with adjustment in MATLAB, for example, when use bar like:

```
bar(randsample(0:0.0001:1,100),randn(100,1))
```

I get an image like this:
[image]

It seems like the bar is too thin to have a good look. After searching for help, I can use the code like:

```
bar(randsample(0:0.0001:1,100),randn(100,1),50)
```

and I get this:
[image]

Seems much better. But if I change the sample number from 100 to 10, the same code won't work.

```
bar(randsample(0:0.0001:1,10),randn(10,1),50)
```

[image]

I hope I have explained my issue clear. It seems like the third parameter of the bar function is a relative width, which correlates to the input size of the first and second parameter. Can I fix the absolute bar width no matter how many data points input? or there is a better function to draw figures like this? Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user @am304 is right about the `width` parameter

What happened in your code is that you set `x` values to results from `randsample(0:0.0001:1,10)`

If you give your plot a width of 1 it means that 2 bars which are directly next to each other would touch each other with an equally spaced `x`.

In your case, you have an irregular `x` spacing. 
The width of the bar is determined by the minimum distance between two `x` values (which you get from `randsample()`). Sometimes this space - and therefore the width of your bar - is very tiny. Sometimes it is broader.

Change the with to `1` and make multiple plots. You will notice that two are always touching each other and no one is overlapping and all the others have spaces in between. If you change the width to `50` the plots will somethimes overlap heavily (depending on the randomness from `randsample`) because your bars are 50 times bigger then the minimum width between two x values.

In case of your `randsample(0:0.0001:1,100)` example it is just more likely that two values are close to each other, therefore increasing the width helps you see something (because the bars overlap).

Comment: Your answer is really helpful. The 'width' parameter in bar function is relative to the minimum distance between elements in the input array x.

Comment: SAMPLE_NUM = 4;
BAR_WIDTH = 0.005;
x = randsample(0:0.00001:1,SAMPLE_NUM);
y = randn(SAMPLE_NUM,1);

x_sorted = sort(x);
minDis = min(x_sorted(2:end) - x_sorted(1:(end-1)));
scaleRatio = BAR_WIDTH/minDis;

bar(x,y,scaleRatio); xlim([0,1]);

This script can generate bar plot with specific width set by BAR_WIDTH no matter how SAMPLE_NUM change

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html):

> `bar(___,width)` sets the relative bar width, which controls the
>   separation of bars within a group. Specify `width` as a scalar value.
>   Use this option with any of the input argument combinations in the
>   previous syntaxes.

The example provided is as follows:

> Set the width of each bar to 40 percent of the total space available
>   for each bar.
>
> ```
> y = [75 91 105 123.5 131 150 179 203 226 249 281.5];
> bar(y,0.4)
> ```

[image]

So bottom line is: the width is specified as a % of the total space available for each bar. Yoru problem comes from the fact that you have far too many bars, so the space available for each bar is tiny. Setting the width to 50 or 5000% of the space available just means that each bar will overlap quite substantially on the neighbouring bars. Because you have so many, the middle plot looks "reasonable" as I suspect a lot of the bars are overlapped and a lot of them are at zero, so you just can't see them. If you go down to a sensible number of bars, as in your last example, then setting the width to 5000% looks ridiculous as you found out.

So to summarise: reduce the number of bars and specify the bar width between >0 and 1 (1 being no gap, all the bars touching each other).

Comment: Thank you for your quick help! I have tried the 'width' parameter, it works well in the second example of my question. But when the input data size change (from 100 to 10), the same ‘width’ scale seems too big. In my project, I can't manually adjust the 'width', so I want to fix the bar width no matter how many data point I input.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to plot things with random x locations is to use [`stem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html). By default, it draws a line from the zero line to the datum, with a circle representing each datum. But this can be modified. For example:

```
stem(randsample(0:0.0001:1,100),randn(100,1), 'Marker','none', 'LineWidth',4)
```

creates a plot similar to your second attempt, but with bars of a fixed width (4 points).